# Windows Form UI Update issue with Task in C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

We are working on a windows application which caters to an engineering calculation which are essentially very long running. So we are basically trying to keep the calculation module separate and working in a separate worker thread and pass it an Action delegate in method signature which will be invoked to report the calculation progress in the UI. The delegate handler declared in the UI will be updating the UI. We found that while a huge loop is running in the calculation, the UI is not showing the periodic progress and only displaying the final result. If a Thread Sleep for 1 millisecond is introduced in the calculation loop, the UI is getting updated correctly. This is not expected behavior as we are executing the calculation using a separate Task and updating the UI using BeginInvoke calls.

I have created a simple application to demonstrate our approach and code so that it is easier to understand. It is obvious that we are missing something very simple but cannot quite pin it down. Will appreciate any insights.

Thanks for reading.

```
private void cmdStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtResultDIsplay.Text = "";
    var maxIterations = long.Parse(txtIterationNo.Text.Trim());

    var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Task<double> calculationTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<double>(
        () => SumRootN(maxIterations, UpdateProgress));

    var handleResultTask = calculationTask.ContinueWith((t) => DisplayResult(t),
        CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, ui);
}
```

---

```
private void DisplayResult(Task<double> calculationTask)
{
    txtResultDIsplay.Text = "Final Calculation Result : " + calculationTask.Result.ToString();
}
```

---

```
private void UpdateProgress(string msg)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        txtResultDIsplay.Text = msg;
    });
}
```

---

```
public double SumRootN(long maxIterations, Action<string> progressUpdateDelegate)
{
    int root = 20;
    double result = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < maxIterations; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        result += Math.Exp(Math.Log(i) / root);
        progressUpdateDelegate(result.ToString("0.00000"));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous, so the UI wont update until the executing method has returned. You should probably simply use the synchronous `Invoke` method instead.

Comment: While your solution is absolutely correct, can you help me understand the reason for it. I thought that when the delegate is invoked from the worker thread, the worker thread would hit the UI update method. Now if it sees an Invoke call, the worker will be blocked till the UI updated is completed and the will be able to resume its work, while, if a BeginInvoke call is used, being asynchronous, it will return immediately and the worker can resume its work. Obviously incorrect based on the program execution result. Can you help correct it.

Comment: Also can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The difference is subtle - `BeginInvoke` schedules the work on the UI thread and continues immediately. `Invoke` schedules the work on the UI thread and then _blocks until it is done_

Comment: How often is `UpdateProgress` being called? It is possible to flood the UI context with high priority work and block the rest of the UI thread. This would explain why you sleep worked - it allowed the UI context to process other messages.

Comment: @Gusdor UpdateProgress is actually getting called very frequently. So it is possible that the the UI context is getting flooded with the lots of work but my line of reasoning was that since I am using BeginInvoke, it would queue the work items and leave it to the UI thread scheduler to execute the paint tasks. Since the UI is pretty much left idle while the calculation is going on, I cannot see a reason why the update will get blocked until the method returns. Meybe my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible you are flooding the UI thread with your progress updates. You need to find a way to prevent lots of updates occurring.

We can solve the problem using tasks!

```
Task progressTask = null;
private void UpdateProgress(string msg)
{
    //only schedule work if the task if not running
    if(progressTask == null || progressTask.IsCompleted) //updates will end if there is an exception!
    {
        //Create a task representing the update
        progressTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<object>(BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtResultDIsplay.Text = msg)), this.EndInvoke)
            .ContinueWith(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)); //add a sleep on the end
    }
}
```

Note that locking will not do here as you want to skip the update if there is already an update occurring.